# WPF DataGridCell LostFocus event stops bubbling at DataGridRow

Tags: wpf, datagrid, focus, routed-events

I can't quite understand what's going on with the following bit of code.

It's a relatively simple `wpf` datagrid which displays an `ObservableCollection` of objects. If I select a row, and press the delete key, a `LostFocus` event is fired from the `DataGridCell`. Using Snoop, I can look at the elements that receive this routed (bubbling) event. It starts at `DataGridCell`, and bubbles up the visual tree until it hits the `DataGridRow`, but then it stops (This is all evident in Snoop which displays both unhandled and handled events).

My understanding of bubbling events has led me to believe the `LostFocus` event should bubble all the way up to the parent window.

What gives?

```
    <Window x:Class="ApplicationName.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Grid x:Name="_grid">
            <DataGrid
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                HeadersVisibility="Column"
                CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                SelectionUnit="FullRow">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"
                                Header="FirstName"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}"
                                Header="LastName"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Information}"
                                Header="Information"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

The code-behind:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Person> _items = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        public ViewModel()
        {
            _items.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Homer", LastName = "Simpson", Information = "Father" });
            _items.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Bart", LastName = "Simpson", Information = "Son" });
            _items.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Santa's", LastName = "Little Helper", Information = "Dog" });

        }

        public ObservableCollection<Person> Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Information { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Datagrid columns are not the part of VisualTree.

Comment: That's true, but DataGridCells and DataGridRows are part of it.

Answer (score 0):

If the parent Window's `LostFocus` event fires, this means that the focus is not in the parent Window any more. Do you expect this behavior? I think this is not your case. The `DataGridRow` losts focus, the `DataGridCells` lost focus, but not the parent Window.

Comment: I don't expect the parent window to lose focus - just for it to get a chance to handle the DataGridCell's LostFocus event.